# Why does explicit method specialization of a template class work without its prototype declaration inside the class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I am working with the following simple example

```
struct foo
{
    template <typename t>
    void funct(t a , t b)
    {
        std::cout << "Primary template called";
    }
};

template<>
void foo::funct<std::string> (std::string a , std::string b)
{
   std::cout << "Specialized";
}
```

The above code is fine and runs , however I am a bit confused the method declared outside the class  which is :

```
    template<>
    void foo::funct<std::string> (std::string a , std::string b)
    {
       std::cout << "Specialized";
    }
```

does not even have a signature inside the class. I was under the assumption that the above code would work even if I added the signature of the method to the class and made it look like this which unfortunately is wrong

```
struct foo
{
    template <typename t>
    void funct(t a , t b)
    {
        std::cout << "Primary template called";
    }

    template<>                                                 ---->Added Extra
    void funct<std::string> (std::string a , std::string b);   ----->Added Extra
};

 template<>
    void foo::funct<std::string> (std::string a , std::string b)
    {
       std::cout << "Specialized";
    }
```

My question is why does it behave like this ? The method outside the class/struct assumes there is a method with the signature

```
  funct(std::string a , std::string b);
```

but there is not.I would appreciate it if someone could explain this behaviour.

Comment: why not overload the function?

Comment: I understand I could overload the functions. I am just experimenting and learning about templates. I was curious as to why this happens when dealing with templates

Comment: I think it is because the function is already declared by the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explicit specialization will cause an implicit instantiation, no need to declare it explicitly here.

14.7.3$6 Explicit specialization [temp.expl.spec]

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is
>   explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared
>   before the first use of that specialization that would cause an
>   implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in
>   which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

And, the explicit specialization can't be declared in class scope.

14.7.3$2 Explicit specialization [temp.expl.spec]

> An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing
>   the specialized template.

So, if you want you can add the explicit specialization declaration explicitly outside the class scope, even if doesn't make much sense here.

```
template<>
void foo::funct<std::string> (std::string a , std::string b);
```

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/DEdavs)